# Why is my form always unbound?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django, and I am trying to use django-friends in my website.

Here is a form from [django-friends](https://github.com/jtauber/django-friends/blob/master/friends/forms.py#L19):

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class UserForm(forms.Form):
...     
...     def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.user = user
...         super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> f = UserForm({})
>>> f.is_bound
False
```

The [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) said that "passing an empty dictionary creates a bound form with empty data", but why the result is unbound (f.is_bound is False)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happenning here is that `UserForm` uses the first argument (`user`) to initalize its  internal state, so it doesn't pass anything to `forms.Form`. To get the expected behaviour, you can pass an extra argument:

```
>>> f = UserForm(None, {})
>>> f.is_bound
True
```

Answer (score 12):

Your `__init__` statement is swallowing the first argument.

Remove `user=None` from your init statement, and perhaps pull it from the `kwargs` instead.

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        # now the form is actually receiving your first argument: args[0] == {}
```